# Ethereum Wallet Backup

Tags: ether, wallets, backup

Some time ago, me and a friend created a Ethereum Wallet and purchased some ETH. We created the wallet on my Computer but because of some issues, I needed to reinstall windows. I thought I copied all of the Ethereum files for a backup but I think I missed some.
Can I recreate my wallet and if so, what do I have to do for this?

I hope someone can help me.

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you used the Ethereum geth client, then the key information required to access the accounts was in the folder "keystore". If you have lost this data, then it is impossible to restore access to the accounts.